# How to tell Devise which view to render after failed login/registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I do have the case that an app has two ways which it displays the login form. Lets say they are 'View 1' and 'View 2'. The 'View 1' is configured as default view for Devise. Therefor if the user tries to log in on the 'View 2' and enters some wrong credentials, Devise renders 'View 1'. How can I tell Devise which of the views it needs to render in case the login or the registration fails?

Comment: Here is a way: http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2013/01/custom-redirect-after-login-fail-in-devise

Comment: Thanks. Just trying to figure out how to get this working :-)